# In C++, using luabind, call function defined in lua file?

Tags: c++, function, lua, call, luabind

Say I have a lua file:

```
--functions.lua
function testadd(a, b) 
    return a+b
end
```

How would I use luabind to load that file, and call that function- something like:

```
//test.cpp
extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
}
#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>
#include <luabind/function.hpp> 

int main() {
    lua_State *myLuaState = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(myLuaState);
    luaL_loadfile(myLuaState, "functions.lua");
    luabind::open(myLuaState);
    int value = luabind::call_function<int>(myLuaState, "testadd", 2, 3);
    lua_close(myLuaState);
}
```

But this returns an error:
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'luabind::error'
what(): lua runtime error
Aborted**

So, what is the proper syntax for doing what I want to do?
(From the looks of the error it seems to be a problem with the syntax in the lua file, but I don't think it is...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to call `luaL_dofile` instead of `luaL_loadfile` here.

Comment: But how would I get the results?

Comment: oh, I see what you mean. Thanks!