# Segfault when trying to call lua functions defined in a table

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I am trying to solve this seg fault problem, arised when a lua function defined in a table is called from C++ using luabind. Here is C++ the code (borrowed from [In C++, using luabind, call function defined in lua file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314136/in-c-using-luabind-call-function-defined-in-lua-file), and http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/How-to-call-a-Lua-function-which-has-been-defined-in-a-table-td7583235.html ):

```
extern "C" {
#include <lua5.2/lua.h>
#include <lua5.2/lualib.h>
#include <lua5.2/lauxlib.h>
}


#include <iostream>
#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>
#include <luabind/function.hpp>

int main() {
    lua_State *myLuaState = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(myLuaState);
    luaL_dofile(myLuaState, "test.lua");
    luabind::open(myLuaState);

    luabind::object func = luabind::globals(myLuaState)["t"]["f"]; // Line #1
    int value = luabind::call_function<int>(func, 2, 3); // Line #2
    std::cout << value << "\n";
    lua_close(myLuaState);
}
```

and here is the lua code:

```
t = { f = function (a, b) return a+b end }   -- Line #3
```

The program is compiled with

```
g++ test.cpp -I/usr/include/lua5.2 -llua5.2 -lluabind
```

The output of the cpp program is

```
5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

with the backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7bb0a10 in lua_rawgeti ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so.0

#1  0x00007ffff7bc27f1 in luaL_unref ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so.0

#2  0x0000000000401bb5 in luabind::handle::~handle() ()

#3  0x0000000000401e15 in luabind::adl::object::~object() ()

#4  0x000000000040185c in main ()
```

**However, I don't see any error if the lua function is instead defined as a global,** i.e change line #3 to read

```
f = function (a, b) return a+b end
```

and line #2 is changed to

```
int value = luabind::call_function<int>(myLuaState, "f", 2, 3);
```

So my question is:

- Why is this happening?
- Is this the correct way to call functions in a table?

Per @EtanReisner comment, the correct solution is:

Putting the call_function part in a scope block would solve this problem.

Comment: It would seem when the luabind object goes out of scope the destructor is expecting the lua state to be valid.  Here's an excerpt from the docs: `It's important that all instances of object have been destructed by the time the Lua state is closed. The object will keep a pointer to the lua state and release its Lua object in its destructor.`

Comment: Indeed, this appears to be a luabind destructor issue. Can you manually dispose of your luabind objects before you call lua_close?

Comment: @Etan: I think one simply has to change `luabind::object func = ...; ...; lua_close(luastate)` to `{ luabind::object func = ...; ...; } lua_close(luastate)`

Comment: Introducing a scope block like that might very well work, yes. Assuming things dispose immediately at scope exit and aren't delayed to a gc cycle or something.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @EtanReisner. I have verified putting things in a scope block, seg fault disappears.